# How to allow users to checkin in my app without posting to the user's wall?

Tags: user-interface, facebook-graph-api, checkin

Hi I am currently building a facebook app that allows users to checkin for themselves and others and post annonymously on our app main page. I checked the API for developers and only found something like checkin and post on user's wall. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're asking here, you want to check users into a Facebook page, but not have that Checkin appear on their feeds? If so, there's no way to do this. If not, i'm not sure what you're asking, please clarify and i'll try to answer again